# Subtracting row values independently of column address

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a columns of month1, month2, etc, and row of fields, each of these have values and I want to substract Same row in next COLUMN from previous:

`=((COLUMN() & ROW(2))-(COLUMN()-1 & ROW(2)))`

But EXCEL syntax and logic  is beyond my understanding. I just want to address column independently so I can c&p same formula instead of manually writing for each 30+ cells:
B2-A2, C2-B2, D2-C2, etc etc:

**EXAMPLE:**

[image]

**Current formula I use:**

`=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),B2-A2, "")`

What I want:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(COLUMN() -1 & 2),COLUMN() & 2-COLUMN() -1 & 2, "")`

Independent column definition

Comment: please mock up some data and expected outcome.  It will help use visualize what it is you want.

Comment: Are you putting the formulas in the same cell that you are doing the math.  for example, are you putting `=B2-A2` in `B2`?

Comment: @ScottCraner added

Comment: Interwebs derped, now it is on

Comment: where do you put the formulas, are these circular references?

Comment: If you drag/fill the cell the column and row will change.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want them to be independent. For example, this will work for summary: `=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(11,COLUMN())))`

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute references for rows and relative references for columns.

Your formula can be revised as

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A$2),B$2-A$2, "")
```

then copy the formula to other cells. 
Does it answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it does not work. I don't want it be dependent and use "drag & drop" feature like with manual definition, I want it to be independent like example with SUM I provided: `=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(11,COLUMN())))`